# Keyframe animation won't move from first part to last in Safari

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

This works perfectly in all other browsers, but for some reason Safari won't allow it to move past the first part. It starts at the 25% width, but then it doesn't move to 80%, it just stays at 20%

```
@-webkit-keyframes page-load {
 0% {
        width: 25%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@keyframes page-load {
    0% {
        width: 25%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
.page-loading::before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    height:10px;
    width:75%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: #e63452;
    -webkit-animation-name: page-load;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2000ms;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation: page-load infinite ease-out 2s;
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

Does anyone know any solutions to make this work in Safari? I tried add different webkit rules to see if it'll change anything but it doesn't work. It actually worked randomly 2-3 times, and never again. (interestingly worked before I added the webkits)

Edit:

Here's the javascript that I'm using (Because safari has this annoying cache that it does, so I delay for a few milliseconds for the animation to take effect:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    // get all links
var allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");
 
// add an onclick handler on each link to delay the redirect by 100 ms
// so we can update the DOM before it is frozen by the browser.
allLinks.forEach((e) => {
   // todo: if there are any links you want to filter out, do it here.
 
   e.onclick = () => {
       document.body.classList.add("page-loading"); // add a class or make an loading animation.
    
       // delay the redirect by 100 milliseconds.
       setTimeout(() => (window.location.href = e.href), 20); // 100 ms is enough time.
       return false; // this will make sure the browser does not redirect
   }; 
});
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
  if (!event.persisted) {
    return;
  }
  document.body.classList.remove('page-loading');
});
}, false);
```

**EDIT**: These are the only codes I have active

Comment: make sure to include the HTML so people can reproduce the problem and help you out

Comment: Are you on IOS? Please show enough code so we can run this and see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: Please show us enough code so that we can run this for ourselves. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example We can't run it without the HTML. And please show what you have as a doctype and in the head. Also please could you tell us exactly what happens when you run the snippet in my attempt at an answer? Including whether there is anything in the browser console. Also please say what operating system you are on - is it IOS?

Comment: I've had another look at your code. You are waiting for only 20ms. This is getting on for being just one frame's worth and if the browser already has the page in cache why wouldn't it show it almost immediately? Have you tried waiting for say 10 seconds to see whether the animation works or not?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

JS has been added to the question. This shows a pause before the redirect takes place. But the pause is very short (20ms as currently shown).

There is nothing wrong with your code. You just don't see the red bar animate because the system isn't having to wait to load the new page any more than the 20ms you have given it.

Here's two scenarios:

So, I am trialling a longer wait time and with the recently added JS from the question:

```html
<style>
  @-webkit-keyframes page-load {
    0% {
      width: 25%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes page-load {
    0% {
      width: 25%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  
  .page-loading::before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #e63452;
    -webkit-animation-name: page-load;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation: page-load infinite ease-out 2s;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">click me</a>
</body>
<script>
  const e = document.querySelector('a');
  e.onclick = () => {
    document.body.classList.add("page-loading"); // add a class or make an loading animation.

    // delay the redirect by 100 milliseconds.
    setTimeout(() => (window.location.href = e.href), 20000); // 100 ms is enough time.
    return false; // this will make sure the browser does not redirect
  };
</script>
```

This works fine on Safari for me (I am on IOS). The red animated line shows for the 20 seconds and then the redirect happens. (well, actually it doesn't because of SO's snippet framing system, but it does try to redirect after the 20 seconds).

So, there is nothing wrong with the code on Safari. It's just that in real life if the new page doesn't have to wait to be fetched it will be shown after 20ms (given the code as it currently stands in the question). 20ms is just about enough time for a frame to be shown so the red shows without animation because there's no time left for it.

To show this is so here's the snippet with 20ms wait time:

```html
<style>
  @-webkit-keyframes page-load {
    0% {
      width: 25%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes page-load {
    0% {
      width: 25%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  
  .page-loading::before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #e63452;
    -webkit-animation-name: page-load;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation: page-load infinite ease-out 2s;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">click me</a>
</body>
<script>
  const e = document.querySelector('a');
  e.onclick = () => {
    document.body.classList.add("page-loading"); // add a class or make an loading animation.

    // delay the redirect by 100 milliseconds.
    setTimeout(() => (window.location.href = e.href), 20); // 100 ms is enough time.
    return false; // this will make sure the browser does not redirect
  };
</script>
```

I see the red as a quick flash and then the new page (or the redirect error message) comes in.